# Difference between air gap calculation in an inductor with respect to practical measurement

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

I've designed a 75 μH inductor with EI3329s. Winding is 23 turns of two parallel 1 mm wire. From calculations, rhe air gap must be 1.1 mm in the center post of the core. I've neglected the reluctance of core within the calculations and just considered the air gap reluctance.

N = 23
Lg = 1.1 (mm)
N·i = Rg·A·B
Rg = Lg/(μ<sub>0</sub>·A)
L = 75 μH = N<sup>2</sup>/Rg
A = 127 (mm<sup>2</sup>)
i = 10.5 (A)

The problem here is that in practice, I distributed the air gap to all posts of ferrite, not just the center post. So, I expect to achieve 75 μH with less air gap rather than 1.1 mm, maybe about 0.5 mm. But when practically adjusting the air gap to set the inductance at 75 μH, thecair gap was about 1.2 mm, not 0.5 mm.

So if I make the air gap just in the center post, it would be about 2 to 2.5 mm for 75 μH. Can anyone explain why this is so? It seems that all of my air gap calculations should be multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations for the reluctance are a simplification. They neglect the stray magnetic flux that effectively increases the area of the air gap:
[image]

This effect can be very significant. The effect is plotted for two different rectangular core profiles below. You can see that the effective area could be about twice as large as the area of your ferrite core.

[image]

<sub>Source: Induktivitäten in der Leistungselektronik</sub>

Comment: What is the scale for a or b in the plot?  Should the axis be l_g/a or something like that?  Or is this scaled to EE33 dimensions?  (It feels right based on my experience with EE33s!)

Comment: I calculated again with fringing factor. With the 6.18 formula mentioned in the book written by Manfred Albach. Calculation says that with a 1mm air gap in the center and side limbs, inductance would be about 55uH but practically it is about 90uH.